# Evenly distribute X values within a given range

Tags: math, formula

This is driving me nuts. I am looking for the formula to evenly calculate *x* values within a range of *minimum* and *maximum* values. For instance...

`min = 4`
`max = 20`
`x = 3`

Should equate to...

`= 8, 12, 16`

I feel like the answer is right in front of my face, I'm sure I covered it at some point during one of my math or statistics courses, but I just can't puzzle it out. I have looked at similar questions here, but they are all programming specific and aren't really shedding any light for me. I would think there has to be a basic formula for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a comment automatically added when voting to close a question with a custom comment - so, yes, I did what you've suggested :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

assuming t = 1..x:

```
a[t] = min+t*(max-min) / (x+1)
```